# "armaments + noun" vs "armament + noun"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, attributive-nouns

a name:
*[Military Armament Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Armament_Corporation)*
That is, we have the phrase:
**(1)** *armament corporation*

But in dictionaries, I see the following:
*armament**s** industry / programme / production / factory*
That is, we should say:
**(2)** *armament**s** corporation*

What is the difference between (1) and (2)?
If we use "*armament(s)*" attributively, then when do we need to say it in singular form and when in plural?

Comment: "Military Armament Corporation" is the name of a company.  It's a proper noun. It doesn't mean "the armaments industry".   Most dictionaries do not list proper nouns or the names of companies.  You cannot change a proper noun. It's the name that has been chosen. It would be incorrect to pluralise "Armament" here because that is not the name of the company.

Comment: armaments' industry. Except some BrE usage like: drugs policy. Usually weapons is better than armaments. Proper names can be anything like your 1). No rules apply there.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between singular and plural in OP's context, but we *have* shifted to preferring the latter over the past century. Note that [today we usually just use ***arms***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20armament%20company%2Can%20armaments%20company%2Can%20arms%20company&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) for the "attributive noun used adjectivally"...

[image]

Also note that there's no such thing as ***an arm company*** or ***an arm race*** in English, so we can't *exactly* say that ***arm*** is "short for" singular ***armament***, because the short singular version *never* occurs as an "attributive noun".

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure there are other discussions of the general idea elsewhere here at ELL. Hopefully someone will link them in the comments. To discuss it in this specific context a little more carefully than [FF did](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/331356/52137):

**The *general rule* is that nouns being used as attributives** (basically adjectives) **aren't pluralized**: *She's 6 feet tall* but *She's a 6-foot-tall battle robot.*

**We ignore that if it causes needless confusion**. *Arm massage* is for any given arm. The *arm trade* creates an unhelpful mental image where *arms trade* points out that you specifically intend the only-ever-plural sense of the word. Ditto *arms manufacturer*, *arms dealer*, &c.

**Nouns ending in *-ment* are a little special**. They can *either* be the abstract noun of a process (here, the action of providing weapons) *or* the general word for the things specifically involved in that process (here, weapons). The abstract noun is almost always only singular. The general word can be singular like normal for attributives *or* it can be plural. You might use the second one to emphasize the abstract sense *isn't* meant or to create a mental image of all the different kinds of things that can be used for the process.

Bringing that together:
**Military Armament Corporation**: A specific name (don't change that) that can mean *either* that it claims to arming the military *or* that it provides military-quality weapons. It might only sell one specific kind of weapon though, despite its generalized name.

**Military Armaments Corporation**: A specific name (don't change that) that *only* means that it provides military-quality weapons. It heavily implies that the company makes several/many different kinds of weapons.

Similarly, all **military armaments corporations** could be considered **military armament corporations** but not necessarily the reverse. (There aren't many but there are some kinds of equipment that can be understood to arm militaries but aren't actually arms themselves: armored personnel carriers come to mind.)